Why does __dirname suddenly change?
I'm attempting to automatically locate a specific file that I have stored in my backend for my tlsFile when connecting to DocumentDB. However, I'm finding this odd behavior where __dirname suddenly changes if the full path name actually resolves to the path of the file name I want.
(Of course, if this is a bad practice in terms of cybersecurity let me know; this project is fortunately not public.)
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  tlsCAFile: path.join(__dirname, process.env.TLSCAFILE), //Specify the DocDB; cert
  tlsAllowInvalidCertificates: process.env.MODE !== "prod",
  tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: process.env.MODE !== "prod",
  directConnection: true,
  auth: {
      username: process.env.MONGODBUSER,
      password: process.env.MONGODBPASS
  }
});

This results in an ENOENT, as such below:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'relative/path/to/key.pem'
    at async open (node:internal/fs/promises:639:25)
    at async Object.readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1246:14)
    at async MongoClient._connect (/Users/<REDACTED>/node_modules/lib/mongo_client.js:163:32)
    at async MongoClient.connect (/Users/<REDACTED>/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:142:13)
    at async MongoClient.connect (/Users/<REDACTED>/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:295:16) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'relative/path/to/key.pem' // this does NOT have __dirname
}

Why, when I change the process.env.TLSCAFILE to a non-existent location, does __dirname suddenly return?
Once I change process.env.TLSCAFILE from relative/path/to/key.pem to relative/path/to/keythatdoesntexist.pem, this of course results in an ENOENT, but note the change in file name below:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/full/path/to/directory/relative/path/to/keythatisntthere.pem'
    at async open (node:internal/fs/promises:639:25)
    at async Object.readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1246:14)
    at async MongoClient._connect (/Users/<REDACTED>/node_modules/lib/mongo_client.js:163:32)
    at async MongoClient.connect (/Users/<REDACTED>/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:142:13)
    at async MongoClient.connect (/Users/<REDACTED>/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:295:16) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/full/path/to/directory/relative/path/to/keythatisntthere.pem' // this DOES have __dirname
}

Addendum:
console.log(path.join(__dirname, process.env.TLSCAFILE))
returns the desired result, which is /full/path/to/directory/relative/path/to/key.pem. I have a feeling it may or may not be related to the MongoClient itself.
I have also attempted doing the following:
const q = (fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, process.env.TLSCAFILE)));
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  ca: q,
  tlsAllowInvalidCertificates: process.env.MODE !== "prod",
  tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: process.env.MODE !== "prod",
  directConnection: true,
  auth: {
      username: process.env.MONGODBUSER,
      password: process.env.MONGODBPASS
  }
});

But oddly, the same error comes up, sourced within the connect call. The stacktrace is the same.

Relative paths don't begin with a /.

Please, provide a way to reproduce. Debug path.join(...) value, should be visible withoutmongo. What said above is true, but a slash won't affect how  path.join works, it forcibly concatenates paths, this is the way it differs from path.resolve. The only way I see it to be possible is that you accidentally reassigned __dirname

Sorry about that. I can edit as such, but it does produce the same result.

Is relative/path/to/key.pem a symbolic link?

It is not. It is directly to the file.

What does console.log(path.join(__dirname, process.env.TLSCAFILE), fs.realpathSync(path.join(__dirname, process.env.TLSCAFILE))) log?

The console also prints out the same discrepancy:
/full/path/to/directory/relative/path/to/key.pem,
but putting it as an option in MongoClient only gives relative/path/to/key.pem.

I found the source of the issue. There was no bug. This was actually caused by a separate instance of MongoDB.connect hidden in MongoStore.create in a separate file, where I didn't not prepend process.env.TLSCAFILE with __dirname, which gave off the illusion that __dirname was changing, when it wasn't.
I apologize for the confusion this caused, but thank you anyways.
(I figured this out by going through the stacktrace and printing out some debugging statements in the node_modules and reverting them, and found that the program was running it twice.)
